# How to change font color of value in column table with condition with HTML

Tags: html, colors, fonts

i have a column like D i want it to be like colum E.
when its 0 the font color = black, if its > 0 the font color = blue and if its < 0 the font color = red. i already have the expression that i use in visual studio:
=iif(Value = 0, "Black", iif(Value < 0, "Red", "Blue")) but i want it in html

can anyone help me how can i get the same result with html?

```
<font color="Black">Value</font>
```

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You have to use Javascript to check the value and set appropriate color. Show your HTML code please.

Comment: The `<font>` element and its attributes have been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) for I think 10 years or more now.

Answer (score 1):

You need some scripting language support to achieve the solution. Plain html can't handle this. You can also achieve this using some advanced frameworks like angular.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        table, th, td {
            border-spacing: 0px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            text-align: right;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <th>HEADER 1</th>
            <th>HEADER 2</th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
        let rows = [[0, 1], [-1, -2], [0, 1]]
        rows.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
            $('#myTable').append('<tr id="row' + rowIndex + '">');
            row.forEach(cell => {
                if(cell > 0) {
                    $('#row' + rowIndex).append('<td style="color: blue;">' + cell + '</td>');
                } else if (cell < 0) {
                    $('#row' + rowIndex).append('<td style="color: red;">' + cell + '</td>');
                } else {
                    $('#row' + rowIndex).append('<td style="color: black;">' + cell + '</td>');
                }
            });
            $('#myTable').append('</tr>');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```